# How to add a L1 or L2 regularization to weights in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, regression

In tensorflow, we can add a L1 or L2 regularizations in the sequential model. I couldn't find equivalent approach in pytorch. How can we add regularizations to weights in pytorch in the definition of the net:

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden)   # hidden layer
        """ How to add a L1 regularization after a certain hidden layer?? """
        """ OR How to add a L1 regularization after a certain hidden layer?? """
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)   # output layer

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
        x = self.predict(x)             # linear output
        return x

net = Net(n_feature=1, n_hidden=10, n_output=1)     # define the network
# print(net)  # net architecture
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.2)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()  # this is for regression mean squared loss
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I need to regularize weights, with either L1 or L2, which gives best results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally L2 regularization is handled through the [`weight_decay`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.SGD) argument for the optimizer in PyTorch (you can [assign different arguments for different layers too](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#per-parameter-options)). This mechanism, however, doesn't allow for L1 regularization without extending the existing optimizers or writing a custom optimizer.

According to the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L1L2) they use a `reduce_sum(abs(x))` penalty for L1 regularization and a `reduce_sum(square(x))` penalty for L2 regularization. Probably the easiest way to achieve this is to just directly add these penalty terms to the loss function used for gradient computation during training.

```py
# set l1_weight and l2_weight to non-zero values to enable penalties

# inside the training loop (given input x and target y)
...
pred = net(x)
loss = loss_func(pred, y)

# compute penalty only for net.hidden parameters
l1_penalty = l1_weight * sum([p.abs().sum() for p in net.hidden.parameters()])
l2_penalty = l2_weight * sum([(p**2).sum() for p in net.hidden.parameters()])
loss_with_penalty = loss + l1_penalty + l2_penalty

optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_with_penalty.backward()
optimizer.step()

# The pre-penalty loss is the one we ultimately care about
print('loss:', loss.item())
```

Comment: What is a regularization in Python? Don't understand definitions from the web

Comment: The most intuitive explanation I can think of is that it is a technique in machine learning to penalize a model if the model parameters get "too far" from some predefined state. In a sense this restricts the complexity of the model and helps avoid things like overfitting.

Comment: Does `.backward()` take the penalty terms while calculating derivatives?